# Prove that the height of a heap with n nodes is floor(log2n)

Tags: heap

How would I prove that the height of a heap with n nodes is floor(log<sub>2</sub>N)?

Any explanation would be great...

Answer (score 1):

There are 2<sup>height-1</sup> elements in every height of the heap tree.

> 2<sup>0</sup> = 1 node at height 1
>
> 2<sup>1</sup> = 2 nodes at height 2
>
> 2<sup>2</sup> = 4 nodes at height 3

Therefore, at height x, you can have (2<sup>0</sup> + 2<sup>1</sup> + ... + 2<sup>x-2</sup>) + (1 to 2<sup>x-1</sup>) = (2<sup>x-1</sup>-1) + (1 to 2<sup>x-1</sup>) = 2<sup>x-1</sup> + (0 to 2<sup>x-1</sup>-1) = 2<sup>x-1</sup> to 2<sup>x</sup> - 1 nodes

So, if you apply floor(log<sub>2</sub>N) on it, you will get (x-1).